# Botão Localização API Maps Google (Android Studio) não exibido

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Android nativo, com a IDE Android Studio, o qual realiza uma integração com a API Google Maps.

Observei em diversos videos que ao ativar a propriedade setMyLocation(True) deveria ativar o botão de localização (Canto direto superior do activity), **porém quando ativo esta propriedade o botão não está sendo exibido**. Já tentei diversas maneira para solucionar o erro, porém ainda não encontrei a solução.

**Detalhes:**

- Estou herdando a classe SupportMapFragment.
- Utilizo a API Location da Google para pegar localização.
- Toda parte da localização está funcionando corretamente, o único problema é este botão que não é exibido.

**Códigos Fonte:**

- *Activity do mapa* (A propriedade setMyLocation(true) é chamada no evento onMapReady

  ```
  public class ActMap extends SupportMapFragment implements 
  OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, 
  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
      LocationListener {

  private GoogleMap mMap;
  private GoogleApiClient googleApi;
  private LocationRequest locationRequest;
  private LatLng myLocation;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getMapAsync(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      if (googleApi != null && googleApi.isConnected()) {
          startLocationUpdate();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if (googleApi != null) {
          stopLocationUpdate();
      }
  }

  // Evento principal, após carregar o mapa
  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
      mMap = googleMap;

      mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      setSettingsMap();
      callConenection();
          }

  // quando conecta na API Location. O Bandle retorna um objeto location
  @Override
  public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
      Location location = 
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApi);

      if (location != null) {
          myLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), 
     location.getLongitude());
          moveCameraMyLocation(myLocation);
      }

      initLocationRequest();
      startLocationUpdate();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
      createMarker("Click no mapa", latLng);
  }


  //resultado do location request
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      myLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), l 
   ocation.getLongitude());
      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Latitude:" + myLocation.latitude + " 
   Longetude:" + myLocation.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

  //------------ FUNCOES PROPRIAS -----------//

  private void moveCameraMyLocation(LatLng latLng) {
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
      mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
  }

  //configurações da requisição da localização que é executada em um 
  intervalo de tempo.
  private void initLocationRequest() {
      locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
      locationRequest.setInterval(10000);//tempo que sera atualizado
      locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000); // tempo minimo que sera 
  atualiza (caso uma outra APP tentar atualizar dentro esse intervao, o 
  metodo não executa}
      locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); 
   // HIGH_ACCURAY é alta precisão (GPS);
  }

  //dispara o locationRequest
  private void startLocationUpdate() {
      LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApi, 
   locationRequest, this);// pegar dados de localização
  }

  //Pausa o location request
  private void stopLocationUpdate() {
      LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApi, 
  this);
  }

  //setando configurações iniciais;
  private void setSettingsMap() {
      try {
          mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
          mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
          mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

          //Eventos
          mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);


      } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Erro ao realizar configuração do 
  mapa. Detalhes: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  }


  // metodo para criar marcadores
  public void createMarker(String title, LatLng position) {
      MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
      marker.title(title);
      marker.position(position);

      mMap.addMarker(marker);
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
  }

  //Conexão com api Location
  private synchronized void callConenection() {
      googleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
              .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
              .addApi(LocationServices.API)
              .build();
      googleApi.connect();
  }
  ```

  *- Layout (XML):*

  ```
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.joao.deliall.ActMap"
   map:mapType="normal"
   map:uiCompass="true"/>
  ```
- *AndroidManifest.xml*

  ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.joao.deliall">

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission 
     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
          android:name=".ActSplashScreen"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
          android:name=".ActMain"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
          android:name=".ActLogin"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_act_login" />
      <!--
           The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string 
        resource.
           (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
           Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to 
        sign the APK.
           You need a different API key for each encryption key, including 
       the release key that is used to
           sign the APK for publishing.
           You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in 
         src/debug/ and src/release/. 
      -->
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
          android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

      <activity
          android:name=".ActMap"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_act_map"></activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Felizmente encontrei o problema, chega a ser ridículo de tão simples.
O detalhe é que a navbar estava tampando o botão, coloquei um LinearLayout vertical e resolveu o problema.